# DynamicConfigurationService object is getting null

Tags: java, maven, jax-rs

```
 public static List<ActiveDescriptor<?>> addClasses(ServiceLocator locator, boolean idempotent, Class<?>... toAdd) {
//Getting Null Here dcs=null.so getting java.lang.NullPointerException..any help would be appreciated
        DynamicConfigurationService dcs = (DynamicConfigurationService)locator.getService(DynamicConfigurationService.class, new Annotation[0]);
        DynamicConfiguration config = dcs.createDynamicConfiguration();
        LinkedList<ActiveDescriptor<?>> retVal = new LinkedList();
```

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer-6ab7a896==org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer@78256222{jsp=null,order=1,inst=true,async=true,src=EMBEDDED:null}
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:642)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:407)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.lambda$initialize$0(ServletHandler.java:731)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:357)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:755)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:379)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:911)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at com.zsassociates.aws.runtime.local.ZSHttpServer.init(ZSHttpServer.java:64)
    at Main.main(Main.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.ServiceLocatorUtilities.addClasses(ServiceLocatorUtilities.java:412)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.ServiceLocatorUtilities.enablePerThreadScope(ServiceLocatorUtilities.java:84)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.AbstractHk2InjectionManager.createLocator(AbstractHk2InjectionManager.java:92)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.AbstractHk2InjectionManager.<init>(AbstractHk2InjectionManager.java:62)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.<init>(ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.java:38)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.Hk2InjectionManagerFactory$Hk2InjectionManagerStrategy$1.createInjectionManager(Hk2InjectionManagerFactory.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.Hk2InjectionManagerFactory.create(Hk2InjectionManagerFactory.java:73)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.createInjectionManager(Injections.java:69)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:259)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:311)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:347)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:624)
    ... 21 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: !STOPPED
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.destroy(HandlerWrapper.java:140)
    at com.zsassociates.aws.runtime.local.ZSHttpServer.init(ZSHttpServer.java:70)
    at Main.main(Main.java:15)
```

Comment: It's hard to tell with the little information we have. I'm also no Glassfish expert so I can't tell what `ServiceLocator` would actually do but a few guesses: it might not be able to map the interface you're looking for to a service (is there an implementation?), the service might not have been loaded yet so the (JNDI?) lookup fails, you're experiencing some form of classloader isolation (what's your package structure and where do servlet and service implementation reside?